# I am trying to use proteus to get dynamic views using json in a simple android app.but I am getting null pointer exception

Tags: android, proteus

I am trying to use proteus to get dynamic views using json in a simple android app.but I am getting null pointer exception.
`

```
 JsonReader readerlayout = new JsonReader(new StringReader("layouts.json"));

 readerlayout.setLenient(true);

  JsonReader readerdata = new JsonReader(new StringReader("user.json"));

 readerdata.setLenient(true);

try {

layout = proteusTypeAdapterFactory.LAYOUT_TYPE_ADAPTER.read(readerlayout);

data = proteusTypeAdapterFactory.OBJECT_TYPE_ADAPTER.read(readerdata);

} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

view = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, data, container, 0);
container.addView(view.getAsView());`
```

despite having **json** files for layout and data in assets folder,i am getting this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.flipkart.android.proteus.value.Layout.type' on a null object reference
```

THanks in advance.

Comment: I can help but probably tomorrow, travelling right now. Try to reverse engineer [proteus-demo](https://github.com/adityasharat/proteus-demo). Also if possible please share the layout and data JSON. Remember to register or use the Proteus Type Adapter Factory with Gson.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest checking out [simple-proteus-demo](https://github.com/adityasharat/simple-proteus-demo).

Primarily you need to do the following things to get proteus working correctly:

1. create a new instance of proteus.
2. register proteus with a ProteusTypeAdapterFactory to deserialize proteus JSONs
3. deserialize layout and data using ProteusTypeAdapterFactory
4. create a new Proteus Context and get a ProteusLayoutInflater
5. inflate the layout
6. get the Android `View` from the `ProteusView` and use it as usual